# Remove a Drawn Polyline from LeafLet Map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, polyline-creation, leaflet-draw

How can I simply just remove this polyline from the map?

```
var pointA =  L.latLng(From.lat, From.lng);
    var pointB =  L.latLng(To.lat, To.lng);

    var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

    var st_line = L.polyline(pointList, {
        color: 'red',
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 0.5,
        smoothFactor: 1
 }).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Just call `st_line.remove(mymap)` or `mymap.removeLayer(st_line)`. Sometimes reading docs can help: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#layer and https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map

Comment: Actually, in my case, there was a scoping issue from where I was trying to remove it. that's why it was not working.
Thank You :).